# Nuget angular-file-upload doesn't install?

Tags: ng-file-upload

I am getting error when try to install nuget package in VS 2015.Would you please help me?

Best Regards.

```
Install-Package : An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'angular-file-upload' from source 'https://github.com/'.
At line:1 char:1

Install-Package angular-file-upload
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

EdiT 1: I changed the nuget packet source and installed from nuget package manager window.

Comment: Is it resolved? If not tag it with nuget

Comment: yep @danial it is resolved.